# SD not setting Image pulled from Firebase Storage

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, sdwebimage

I am following Google's [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui) for getting an image from the storage and then placing it into an imageView using "FirebaseStorageUI", which seems to use SDWebImage.

I have the problem that the image simply is not set. There are no errors in the console. My code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!   
var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
var storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.getHouseID(){ (houseName) -> () in
            if houseName.characters.count > 0 {
                self.houseIDLabel.text = houseName // does work correctly
                let photoRef = self.storageRef.child("\(houseName)/\("housePhoto.jpg")")
                self.housePhotoImageView.sd_setImage(with: photoRef) // not working
                } else {
                print("error while setting image and house name label")
            }
        }
    }
```

My Storage looks like this:

[image]

[image]

The label gets correctly set with the `houseName`, which is also used in the storage path to retrieve the image. Anything I have missed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** I think the problem is that your `awesomehouse/` has a slash in the end.

Try to check which `child()` your are creating: `awesomehouse` or `awesomehouse/`

**2.** The second possible problem is that you are trying to fetch `"housePhoto.jpg"` instead of stored `housePhoto`.

So, it should be:

```
let photoRef = self.storageRef.child("awesomehouse/").child("housePhoto")
self.housePhotoImageView.sd_setImage(with: photoRef) // should work now
```

Or it better to save photo to storage with extension `".jpg"`, then it would be:

```
let photoRef = self.storageRef.child("awesomehouse/").child("housePhoto.jpg")
self.housePhotoImageView.sd_setImage(with: photoRef) // should work now
```

Try both. I think it will solve your problem.

Hope it helps

Comment: Was indeed a path problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ffritz glad 2 hear:)

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that you are not setting this on the main queue.

Try this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.housePhotoImageView.sd_setImage(with: photoRef)
}
```

I don't know if it matters that your image file does not have a file extension, that might also be worth trying. Hope this helps

Comment: Was a path problem. Still you might be right with the file extension.